# ElasticSearch 2.4 : Works well in IDE, but not as JAR

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, jar, executable-jar

ElasticSearch 2.4 client work well when running from Intelli Idea Java IDE. When same code run via jar file `java -jar <jar-path>` gives following error.

`Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{<remote-ip>}{<remote-ip>:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:288)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1226)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56)
    at com.creo.datawarehouse.es.op.imp.IndexOperationImp.createIndex(IndexOperationImp.java:66)
    at com.creo.datawarehouse.es.ElasticSearch.initialise(ElasticSearch.java:27)
    at com.creo.datawarehouse.script.App.main(App.java:37)`

POM dependency:

`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>`

[This question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nonodeavailableexception-no-node-available/6280/2) have not any answer and [what is the jar version for 2.4.0 ES version in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114886/elasticsearch-connector-works-in-ide-but-not-on-local-cluster#39364735).

Please let me know the probable reason or solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of debugging, found its solution. Before mentioning those, quick key notes.

---

1. if els server is 2.4.1, maven jar should also be 2.4.1
2. Add log4j dependencies for more logs in details (found from this).
3. Add shade in plugin section.
4. Nothing to do with IDE (may run initially but to run prod, have to follow above).

> But haven't got answer for why it was running in IDE?

---

Java Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
       <build>
        <plugins>
        [---]
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>injector-2.4.1</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>org.elasticsearch.demo.workshop.injector.runner.Generate</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass>com.your.classss.App</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
           [--]
      </plugins>
  </build>
```